# How to create an Excel application using PIA (2010, version 14.0) and target machine doesn't have MS Office client installed on it

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, pia, office-pia

I'm facing one issue, actually I need to create one application `in C# using VS2012, .Net framework 4.5` which reads excel and do some operation, but the issue is target machine doesn't have MS Office client installed on it.

And one restriction is I can't use the other open assemblies like Open XML etc. I have to only use the **2010 PIA**.

It'll be great if someone can explain me how can implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can not be possible without installing MS Office on server. To use PIA you have to install the MS Office on server. Otherwise, if you doesn't want to install MS Office on server, it's better to use Open XML.